# Content Controls not accepting <,>

Tags: c#, vsto

Currently I am working on MS Word 2007 Addin.I am getting Problem with one custom control.

The ContentControl is having **multiline property to true**.it is accepting values from the database. if any database value is having special characters like <,> the content control will stop showing the data.

Suppose the data in the database is `Male, Female, Children(<5), Children(>10)`, The content control is accepting only upto `Male, Female, Children(`.

For other data like strings, numeric data it is working fine.

Please Help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all familiar with the Office addins but maybe it uses some XML or XAML (which is XML-based) strategy.

In this case [XML escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters/1091953#1091953) or encodings might help.

Try `&gt;` for `>` and `&lt;` for `<`.

Comment: Yep, I suspect you'll need to escape XML reserved chars.